# how to assign multiple variable value from key value of dict in python?

Tags: python

here **HEX2RGB** return dict value after conversion like *{r:255,g:255,b:255}*

```
    rgbValue=HEX2RGB(hex,'dict')
    r,g,b={rgbValue} # not working
```

so how can I assign value of each key *r,g,b* in the variables r,g,b like above method?
or is there any other efficient way?

Comment: `r,g,b = rgbValue.values()`

Comment: @Epsi95: Perhaps you should place this as an answer. You should avoid answering questions in comments.

Comment: Does `HEX2RGB` already support producing a tuple (seems like it supports *something*, since `'dict'` is an argument rather than a hard-coded assumption)?

Comment: @SamMatzko sure, but I want to correct one thing, we should not rely on python dict order (although 3.6+ it is ordered, but we can assume python version beforehand), so it might not be surprising that `rgbValue.values()` can give (b,g,r), (g,b,r) etc, I think Roman's first answer is good one. More fancy and unnecessary one can be 
 `r,g,b = map(rgbValue.__getitem__, ('r', 'g', 'b'))`

Comment: @Epsi95 Ah, that makes sense. Sorry!

Answer (score 5):

Use `operator.itemgetter`, which will not rely on any particular ordering returned by `HEX2RGB`;

```
from operator import itemgetter

dictToTuple = itemgetter('r', 'g', 'b')

r, g, b = dictToTuple(HEX2RGB(hex,'dict'))
```

Comment: your solution is a little overengineerd for this specific case. It's still a very good answer. I did not know the itemgetter until now. Thanks for showing the operator module!

Comment: I would not call this overengineered. It puts a single function from the standard library to its intended use, is more efficient than three separate calls to `get`, and makes no assumptions about the order of the keys in the `dict` argument.

Comment: Ok got your point. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

if your type is a dictionary (assumption cause you wrote {r:255,g:255,b:255})

```
r,g,b = rgbValue.get('r'),rgbValue.get('g'),rgbValue.get('b')
```

More Pythonic way:

```
dict = {'r':255,'g':255,'b':255}
r,g,b = dict.values()

print(r)
print(g)
print(b)
```

Comment: Most pythonic way would be to not name your dictionary `dict` to avoid shadowing the class

Comment: @MadPhysicist true, that's a very good comment. I had not thought of that.

Comment: Note that your second solution only works if the dict keys were created in the specific order r, g, b for versions of Python >= 3.7 where dicts are ordered, and will randomly fail for older versions.